# Nexus 7 Layout Size (Nexus 7 7.02")

Tags: android, android-layout, nexus-7

I'm learning Android development and tried several simple apps using Android Studio. One issue I couldn't figure out is about the Nexus 7 screen (layout) size.

Here is what I did:

1. Use Andriod Studio (latest version: 2.1.1) to create a new project with one empty activity. Didn't change anything and run it on Nexus 7 API 19 (4.4) emulator. The app launched with the default 'Hello, world!' message.
2. I changed res/values/strings.xml like this:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Sample Layout Size (Default)</string>  
</resources>
```

When app launch, the screen is displayed like this:
[screen shot on Nexus 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eexBu.png)

3. I created new folder res/values-large, and created new strings.xml file under it. The content of strings.xml is:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Sample Layout Size (Large)</string>
</resources>
```

I'm expecting when app launch on Nexus 7, the application title will change to **Sample Layout Size (Large)**. However, it did not. It still display app title as **Sample Layout Size (Default)**.

I created another virtual device *Nexus 7 API 23* and launched the app on it, same result.

I launched the app again on *Nexus 9 API 23* and this time the title changed to **Sample Layout Size (Large)**.

I also created another folder, `res/values-sw600dp`, and with a new strings.xml under this dir, specifying app name to be Sample Layout Size (SW 600DP). Not working. Still same result using default value: Sample Layout Size (Default) title.

So it appears to me Nexus 7 is still using default layout. I've read several posts on Stack Overflow regarding Nexus 7 and none of them has the same issue like mine.

I understand this Nexus 7 is an old device so I'm wondering if multi-screen support has changed to handle such devices.

The following is the property of the Nexus 7 emulator:

```
Name: Nexus_7_API_23
CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
Path: C:\Users\Nathan\\.android\avd\Nexus_7_API_23.avd
Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 23)
Skin: nexus_7_2013
SD Card: 100M
hw.dPad: no
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: Nexus 7 2013
vm.heapSize: 64
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.gps: yes
image.androidVersion.api: 23
hw.audioInput: yes
image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86\
tag.id: google_apis
hw.camera.back: none
hw.mainKeys: no
AvdId: Nexus_7_API_23
hw.camera.front: none
hw.lcd.density: 320
runtime.scalefactor: auto
avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 7 API 23
hw.gpu.mode: auto
hw.device.hash2: MD5:47dc70fd92541dd16c19f9efa3e9db62
hw.ramSize: 1536
hw.trackBall: no
hw.battery: yes
hw.sdCard: yes
tag.display: Google APIs
runtime.network.latency: none
hw.keyboard: yes
hw.sensors.proximity: no
disk.dataPartition.size: 800M
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Attached is the configuration for the troubled device.
[avd config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv5eM.jpg)

Comment: I also created another folder res/values-sw600dp and with a new strings.xml under this dir, specifying app name to be _Sample Layout Size (SW 600DP)_. Not working. Still same result using default value: **Sample Layout Size (Default)** title.

Comment: In the future, you should just edit additional information into your question instead of using comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they recommend to use `sw600dp` now but if that does not work you can create `values-large-port` and `values-large-land` folders. Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried with these folders: values-large-port, values-large-land, values-sw600dp-port, none of them worked.

Comment: Weird, I just tried it and it works fine for me in using sw600 and land/port folders.

Comment: What's the exact value of your folder name? values-sw600dp-port? That's strange. I just updated with all property values of my emulator setting. I can't find anything wrong with those settings (they are all default values)

Comment: I think I found the specific reason, but no answer yet. The device I created is **Nexus 7**  whose size is 7.02" with xhdpi resolution. The device @prat use is **Next 7 (2012)**. The app launched as expected on **Next 7 (2012)**, but on the new **Next 7** with xhdpi density, nothing works. My guess is this specific device emulator has a bug.

Comment: Mmmm, I guess you did not create the emulator correctly. I have a Nexus 7 tablet and it works fine using the sw600 and values-large-land or values-large-port. Good luck mate!

Comment: I think you are right. I recreated the emulator and this time it worked. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Sorry, dude. My reputation is too low to make my vote counts. LOL.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try adding

**layout-sw600dp-land-tvdpi**

**layout-sw600dp-port-tvdpi**